# Compare child nodes to control value while parsing XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file organized like this, items under each node are always in alphabetical order:

```
<xml>
    <node id="2">
        <jack>Jack wrote this.</jack>
        <john>John wrote this.</john>
    </node>

    <node id="4">
        <jack>Jack wrote this.</jack>
        <jill>Jill wrote this.</jill>
    </node>

    <node id="9">
        <jack>Jack wrote this.</jack>
        <james>James wrote this.</james>
        <jill>Jill wrote this.</jill>
        <john>John wrote this.</john>
    </node>
</xml>
```

As you can see, not all the names are under each node.  For example, in `<node id="4">`, John and James did not write anything.  For the above example, I'd like my program to return something like this:

```
James did not write 2, 4
Jill did not write 2
John did not write 4
```

I need to keep track of who didn't write what. I am currently parsing the document like this:

```
private static String getTagValue(final Element element)
{
    String theId="";
    if (element.getTagName().startsWith("node")){

        theId = element.getAttribute("id");
        return theId;
    }
    return theId;
}


private static void readXML(String fileName){

    for (int index = 0; index < nodeList.getLength(); index++){

                Node node = nodeList.item(index);
                Element element = (Element) node;

                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){

                    // This prints the node id
                    if(getTagValue(element)!=""){
                        System.out.println(getTagValue(element)+" = I am the node id number!");
                    }

                    // This prints the name
                    else{
                        System.out.println(element.getTagName()+" = I am the name!");
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

What I'd like to do is somehow compare the elements under each node to a "control" list that contains all of the names, and if it doesn't contain a name, it returns the name and its parent node.

In reality, the XML I'm dealing with is much larger, so performance matters, but the concept is the same.  Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain two sets. One is a master set of all names (`A`). The second is a set that you build up during each iteration, of people that answered the question (`B`). Then the people that didn't answer would be `A - B`, and you can do that with [`Collection#removeAll(Collection c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
A.removeAll(B);
```

You mentioned that you wanted to print out in one line what answers a person didn't answer. To do that, you can maintain a map (`Map<String, List<Integer>>`) that maps a person's name into a list of question numbers they didn't answer. You can do this by examining the result of `A.removeAll(B)` at the end of one iteration.

So once you have finished looping through all nodes, you end up with a map that gives you each name associated with a list of questions they didn't answer. You can then iterate over this map and print out what you need.

Answer (score 0):

From a functionality view point, i would say the functionality may go as follows:

- For Each Node node Get all children in the xml file
- Compare the name each each child node against the control sample nodes names
- If the name of the node match, then break the child loop
- if the name does not match until the for loop for the control group is completed then print statement name of control group is not found